# Share a CS file with 2 different projects using Visual Studio 2010 and Subversion

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, svn

We are moving from SourceSafe to Subversion as our source control provider... All is going well so far except I can figure out how you "share" a file between more than one project. In sourcesafe you made a link to the file and then added it to your project, then source safe knew that the file was really just one file.  How do you do the equivalent with Subversion?

Comment: Adding shared files to a project via a link is a VS project feature that stores the relevant path in the project file without copying it to the local directory, what exactly goes wrong when you add one and commit with SVN?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can [add a file as a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx) within Visual Studio directly.

Doing this means you don't have to worry about how your source control will manage things, so long as the referenced file in in source control - the link is managed by VS.

Comment: How does locking and branching/merging work with this approach?

Comment: @Mrchief - how do you mean? The link information is held in the project file.

Comment: Well, can I lock the file from the project that holds the link? Is the lock on the actual CS file or the link? If it's on the link, then the purpose of lock is lost. What if I branch the project with the link, then merge it later, and meanwhile the link has changed/moved, does it still merge properly?

Comment: The lock will be acquired on the file it references (as with any other file) which only points to a single file on the server (mirrored by your workspace directory anyway, as with any other file.)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to share a CS (as in a code file) between 2 projects? From an design aspect, why not extrapolate that file into it's own project and then reference that project from the other projects.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? _This_ is the _right_ thing to do! +1 for that.

Comment: Shared files in a project does not by necessity mean duplicate code. There are many possible file types, ranging from assembly info (*.cs) files to application resources, that are usually part of a production solution and need to be shared throughout it.

Comment: Why would you share assembly info on projects? You are going to be missing relevant information for each project if you just inherit from 1. I can understand XML, Config, and other files like that, but not a compiled file. That should be extracted into it's own project and made into it's own library. That's general practice for all coding languages.

Comment: I'm coming into this very late, but here's another possibility. When you have one common code base that needs multiple sets of references. I'm working on a TFS custom checkin policy, and it needs to work on VS 2008, 2010 and 2012. Each platform need to reference a particular set of assemblies for TFS. You can't just "build and reference" as you suggest here.