# How to define class for using with both WPF and Console Application projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution with two differents projects:

1. `WPF`
2. `Console Application`

I want to define my classes only in one place, I don't want to use `DLL`.

What are my options ?

Comment: Common code = library = dll.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a dll?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share a CS file with 2 different projects using Visual Studio 2010 and Subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152001/share-a-cs-file-with-2-different-projects-using-visual-studio-2010-and-subversio)